# Directory in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, dos

I have to read 2 directories (dir1 and dir2) and create the dir1/dir2 directory.
My question is: What does `cmp al,13` do? When i write `mov ah,01h,int 21h`,in al will be the character that I read,and it's only one character(e.g 'a') so how it's possible to compare al with 0?

```
assume cs:code,ds:data

data segment
mesaj1 db 10,13,'First dir $',10,13
mesaj2 db 10,13,'Second dir $',10,13
dir1 db 30 dup(?)
dir2 db 30 dup(?)
pnf db 10,13,'Path not found.$',10,13
acd db 10,13,'Acces denied, or pathname already exists.$',10,13
gata db 10,13,'The directory was created.$',10,13
data ends

code segment
start:
mov ax,data
mov ds,ax

;read the first direcory
mov ah,09h
mov dx,offset mesaj1
int 21h

mov si,0
mov ah,01h
int 21h
bucla1:
mov dir1[si],al
inc si
int 21h
cmp al,13                    ;HERE
je sf1
mov dir1[si],al
jmp bucla1
sf1:
mov dir1[si],0

;read the second directory
mov ah,09h
mov dx,offset mesaj2
int 21h

mov si,0
mov ah,01h
int 21h
bucla2:
mov dir2[si],al
inc si
int 21h
cmp al,13                     ;HERE
je sf2
mov dir2[si],al
jmp bucla2
sf2:
mov dir2[si],0

mov ah,3Bh 
mov dx,offset dir1
int 21h
jc eroare

mov ah,39h 
mov dx,offset dir2
int 21h
jc er
mov ah,09h
mov dx,offset gata
int 21h

eroare:
cmp ax,3
je pathnotfound
jmp sf

pathnotfound:
mov ah,09h
mov dx,offset pnf
int 21h
jmp sf

er:
cmp ax,3
je pathnotfound
cmp ax,5
je accesdenied

accesdenied:
mov ah,09h
mov dx,offset acd
int 21h

sf:
mov ax,4C00h
int 21h
code ends
end start
```

Comment: `13` is the ascii code for carriage return (enter). That loops reads input until end of line.

Answer (score 1):

Characters retrieved are represented by their ascii character code and code 13 is a carriage return

It is testing whether the character returned by your second call to int 21h is a carriage return. If it is, break out of the loop otherwise continue the loop and process subsequent characters.

```
mov ah,01h       ; 01h = Read character
int 21h          ; Call (do read)
bucla1:
mov dir1[si],al ; Store result
inc si          ; Increase si
int 21h         ; Call again (do read)
cmp al,13       ; Is carriage return?
je sf1          ; Yes, jump out of loop
mov dir1[si],al ; Store result
jmp bucla1      ; Loop
sf1:
mov dir1[si],0  : Null terminate result
```

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Comment: It is worth noting that CR is produced by the enter key.